# Upload de varios arquivos input via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá
Estou precisando fazer o upload de arquivos via ajax, onde cada evento de clicar no input file, eu já faca o upload do arquivo correspondente. Nao estou sabendo fazer isso dinameicamente, ja que o que muda entre um campo e outro e o nome. E como nao repetir as variaveis pra cada nome de input

Arquivo Javascript

```
  $('#btnEnviar').click(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: upload.php, 
                     data: form,
                     processData: false,
                     contentType: false,
                     type: 'POST',
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                     }
                 });
             });
```

Arquivo HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
    Foto 3x4
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="foto3x4" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Upload">
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    Foto 16x9
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="foto16x9" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Upload">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa que o seu form tenha `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Tendo isso, para fazer o upload via ajax, você precisa criar uma FormData:

```
  var form = $("#id_do_seu_form");
  var formdata = false;
  if (window.FormData){
      formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

 $.ajax({
        url: upload.php, 
        data: formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
        }
 });
```

**E como nao repetir as variaveis pra cada nome de input?**

No nome do seu input voce pode colocar `name="foto[]"`

no php faça o seguinte para ler todos:

```
foreach ($_FILES['foto'] as $arq){
   //rotina de upload
}
```

Comment: No caso o type sao files, mas como identificar qual file e referente a foto16x9 e qual e referente a foto3x4?

Comment: Ai nesse caso acredito que você terá que ter mesmo um campo para cada foto mesmo...